Authentication in API Gateway for node.js microservice application
For authentication, I used a middleware in order to check and verify the jwt. But since I decided to create
an API Gateway for the app, I faced this problem. I tried http-proxy-middleware in order to proxy the request
and use that authentication middleware before proxying the request. But now, I want to use nginx as API Gateway
Can you please tell me how to use that authentication method in nginx and after that proxy the request
to the proper route?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
